# how to combine parquet files in S3 into one parquet file using spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, bigdata, parquet

I have 12 parquet files, each file represent monthly New York Taxi pick up and drop information and consist of +500K rows. I want to combine all these 12 files by row into 1 parquet file and save it in S3 to do machine learning model. How I can do that using pyspark
I will upload these 12 files into AWS S3
[files names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTPst.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like, if all files are in same dir:

```
val ds = spark.read.parquet("/path/*").coalesce(1)
ds.write.parquet("/path/single")
```

or

```
val ds1 = spark.read.parquet("/path1/file")
val ds2 = spark.read.parquet("/path2/anotherlocation/file")
val ds = ds1.union(ds2)
ds.coalesce(1).write.parquet("/path/single")
```

That is an example using Scala, you can do the same in Java/Python.

Comment: in python just remove the val ?

Comment: @AbdelhamidShaat sorry I've never used pySpark, but from what I understand the APIs are same. May be you need to try some basic pySpark examples first - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html